# how to access internal memory of ipad programatically in xcode?

Tags: ipad

i want to allocate 1gb of memory of ipad (or iphone) out of total memory to my application programatically..is it possible?if yes, How to do this?

Comment: I think that first you will need to open the iPad and allocate 768Mb physically to the iPad. Otherwise you won't even have enough RAM to allocate :)

Comment: Main RAM memory, you're out of luck, as others have commented.  Flash storage memory, just write some huge files to your app's Documents directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about 1GB of RAM, I would say NO. iPad has only 256Mb RAM